# How to snap to intersection of lines with Classic snapping?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, snapping

The question is as simple as the title.
When I am in Edit session with Classic Snapping enabled and want to snap to an intersection of lines, it does not work.
In order to achieve this, I have to disable the Classic Snapping, so ArcGIS can snap to the intersection.
Is there any way to snap to the intersection of lines with Classic Snapping enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no it cannot be done. Is there any reason why you need to be in "Classic" mode, the snapping toolbar offers up pretty much the same functionality including that useful snap to intersection.

Comment: I have 18 layers and all of them have to be visible. Only on three of them snapping should be enabled. This can be done only through Snapping window of Classic snapping. The toolbar does not give such an option.

Comment: OK, I think you are stuck then, as it seems the snap to intersection is only available through the toolbar.